# How drag & drop and resize comnponents dynamically ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drag-and-drop

I want to drag and drop simple div with text, and also resize it, when I drop it.
I have to use jQuery, but I never works with it.
Right know I have like this code in Head content:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#d1").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

also

```
     <div id="d1" style="width:100px; height:100px;"> 
  <p>Move This Div</p>
</div>
```

At first I want try to move this div, but  can't move it, I don't know why?After that I want to try drop it on table, and resize it.Please can u provide some usefull examples or your own examples.Thank u
P.S.Actually I should move controls of ASP.NET Web Form on table

Answer (score 2):

you need to load jquery library first, so the code will look something like that:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#d1").draggable();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi I have loaded library, unzipped it, and copy this 3 files to my project ASP.NET

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#d1").draggable();
            $("#droppable").droppable({
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).width(ui.draggable.width());
                    $(this).height(ui.draggable.height());
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="d1" style="width:100px; height:100px; border: solid 1px silver;">  
            <p>Move This Div</p> 
        </div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td id="droppable" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                    One
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```